# SQL query - syntax error

Tags: sql, sybase

I have two tables: `Table A` and `Table B`.

Both of them have `Emp-ID` as key field.

`Table A` has 10k records of unique `EMP-IDs`.

`Table B` has 2k records of unique EMP-IDs.

Some of the `EMP-IDs` in `Table B` also exist in `Table A`.

I need to write a query listing all records of `Table A` and records from `Table B` whose `EMP-ID` does `not exist in Table A`. I need to select `Table B` records whose `EMP_TYPE = 'Y'`

```
select EMP_ID, EMP_TYPE
from Table A
where EMP_ID not in(
select EMP_ID from Table B 
where EMP_TYPE='Y' and EMP_ID in(
select EMP_ID,EMP_TYPE from Table B
union all
select EMP_ID,EMP_TYPE from Table A
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select emp_id, emp_type
from a
union all
select emp_id, emp_type
from b
where emp_type = 'Y' and
      not exists (select 1 from a where a.emp_id = b.emp_id);
```

Comment: Pl see my query: it resulted only the record count from Table 1:
There are a few records in EMP2 table which I manually verified that need to be added to the count of EMP1 table. 

select EMP_ID,EMP_TYPE from EMP1 
union all
select EMP_ID,EMP_TYPE from EMP2
where EMP_TYPE='Y' and
     not exists(select EMP1.EMP_ID from EMP1,EMP2
         where EMP1.EMP_ID = EMP2.EMP_ID)

Comment: @Fortune . . . The query in your comment is not the query in my answer.  For one thing, it has a comma in a `FROM` clause, which I *never* have.